# GCC: compile files in a different folder

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I am writing a `Makefile` placed in the root directory of my project.

Here is my project directory tree:

```
project:
     Makefile
     README
     assets/
     build/
     src/
```

Actually in `Makefile` I'm prepending each file with a variable to tell to `gcc` where find the file:

```
gcc -c $(SOURCE_DIR)file.c
```

I'd like to compile `.c` source files placed in the directory `src` without change the working directory in the `Makefile` or prepending the `SOURCE_DIR` to each file that I have to compile.

**Is there any way to do this?**

P.S. I've read manual (`man gcc`) looking for some `gcc` options. I found that `-L` or `-l` could help me, but I didn't understand their usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way, like the autotools do, would be write a `Makefile` in `src` dir, and then in your main `Makefile` call that `sub Makefile`:

```
programs:
        make -C $(SOURCE_DIR) the_program
```

This case, you can build the program no matter you are in the main directory or in the src directory.